# In-app Billing for several devices

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I have an android app, in which user can purchase some items by Google Play In-app Billing. User has several devices under one account and in each device user install this app. Can i bind purchased items to concrete device?

Comment: Nope. The item purchased is intended per google account

Comment: According to my knowledge, I think yes it will be possible for the one time purchase, I haven't tested it but you can queryInventory() method call before purchasing the item. you may get the purchase status. But it should be only happens when user must choose same account for both the devices.